# highcharts redraw and reflow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to build a dynamic page that has any number between 1-4 graphs on it that can be added or removed as needed but I have run into a huge problem and I can't seem to get the graph to resize after resizing the containing div. for example if I add a graph on the page it will be width 800, then click a button to add another graph it should resize to be 400 a piece but I cannot make it happen. As a very simplistic model I have the following

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: 'line',
          width: 300
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Width is set to 300px'
      },

      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      },

      series: [{
          data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
      }]
  });
  $('#resize').click(function() {
      $('#container').attr('style', 'width: 800px');
      $("#container").highcharts().reflow();
      console.log($('#container').width());
  });
});
```

now when that is run it will log 800 to the dev tools window in chrome but the graph will not resize. I have tried both redraw() and reflow() as suggested in the documentation for highcharts. I even setup a really quick demo on jsfiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/7cbsV/
can anyone please help me. It is kind of important. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using simple `chart.setSize(w,h)`? See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize).

```
$("#container").highcharts().setSize(800, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the width of the chart from

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
      type: 'line',
      width: 300
  },
```

so that it is like this

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
      type: 'line'
  },
```

and set the container width to 300 like this

```
#container {
   width: 300px;
}
```

then just resize the container div as you are already doing. the chart will resize according to the width of the container div.

hope this helps.